# Does the Staircase Paradox not contradict the Monotone Convergence Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, measure-theory

I recently came across the Staircase Paradox (or Rising Sea Level Paradox) and have been trying to reconcile it with the Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT) in Measure Theory. The Staircase Paradox is illustrated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staircase_paradox

In my Measure Theory course, I learned about the Monotone Convergence Theorem, which states that if $f_n$ is a sequence of non-negative, measurable real-valued functions that converges pointwise and monotonically to $f$, then we should observe $\mu(f_n) \uparrow \mu(f)$

The Staircase Paradox involves constructing a sequence of functions where each step gets narrower and taller, converging pointwise to a limit function. The paradox arises as the measures (integrals) of these functions do not seem to converge to the measure of the limit function, despite the pointwise convergence.

I'm trying to understand how the Staircase Paradox fits with the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Can someone shed light on this apparent contradiction or clarify the conditions under which the Monotone Convergence Theorem applies in this context?

Comment: The staircase paradox constructs a sequence of paths, not functions.

Comment: The quantities present in the paradox are not the areas under the curves (which is what MCT would apply to), but their lengths.

Comment: I understand but the paths in this case can be understood as the graphs of real-valued functions. Wouldn't continuity of measure theorem apply to their lengths as that is their Lebesgue measure?

Comment: They are not the graphs of real-valued functions. They don't pass the vertical line test.

Comment: Which measure would you apply the continuity of measure theorem to?

Comment: why don't you write up your supposed counterexample - many times when one starts writing things up, things become clearer than when thinking aloud

Comment: @jwhite true in this example they aren't strictly functions, but this is beside the point - could easily manipulate the example, eg using triangles and the paths being more and more fine dissections of this triangle

Comment: @jwhite using Lebesgue measure on the set that is the graph containing these points

Comment: 2 dimensional or 1 dimensional Lebesgue mesure?

Comment: @JonathanZ 1 dimensional (the graph is a skewed line)

Comment: Oops, the comments keep switching been the measure of sets and the integrals of functions. Which are you asking about? (I'll add that the notation $\mu(f)$ is not one I'm used to. Either $\int f d\mu$ for the integral of a function f, or $\mu(A)$ for the measure of a set A, would make me happier.)

Comment: @JonathanZ I am asking about the length of the sequence of paths, to be interpreted as a measure. Sorry the notation is not pleasing to you, it is the one provided by my Graduate professor.

Comment: $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure is a measure on $\mathbb{R}$. These are sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You say "the graph is a skewed line." Which graph? There are infinitely many. 

Can you say exactly what measure you're using on what subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which assigns the path length to every continuous path in that set?